# Vim: set mouse to current cursor position

Tags: vim, mouse-position

I use vim with the option `set mouse=a` so I can move the vim cursor quickly by pointing and clicking (preferably with my laptop keyboard trackpoint). However, I sometimes also use vim keys to set the cursor (e.g. to another split window). Because of this two way vim cursor manipulation, I sometimes find it annoying that the mouse is at some other far away position I previously clicked on when all I want to do is e.g. move the cursor by a few lines from its current position. I am aware of movement with the keys `i j k l H L M` etc. but sometimes pointing and clicking is so much faster, especially if you want to go to a specific column of a line.

By the way, this is what ChatGPT came up with as a solution to this problem:

```
" Function to set the mouse position to match cursor position
function! SetMousePosition()
    let l:winpos = getpos('.')
    let l:mousecmd = "\e[" . l:winpos[1] . ";" . l:winpos[2] . "H"
    call system("printf '" . l:mousecmd . "' >/dev/tty")
endfunction

" Mapping to call the function when moving the cursor
au CursorMoved * call SetMousePosition()
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Maybe I have to use another terminal (I use Ubuntu gnome-terminal)?
I know this all sounds very picky, but isn't that what we all love about vim, being able to customize it to ones specific needs.
Or maybe I need a different workflow of navigating the cursor altogether. I am open for suggestions!

Comment: I just realized the code ChatGPT came up with cannot work because its definitely missing some transformation from the cursor position (line/column space) to pixel coordinates (screen space)

Comment: Ok so, with `xdotool mousemove` you can sort of get it to work, but its impractical because 1. the mouse cursor doesnt stay hidden when it is moved and 2. you have to set a fixed offset to the cursor-mouse transformation, so when you move the terminal window around, everything breaks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to supply additional information. Comments are to ask for clarifications, not to extend your question. Also, do you want an answer to your question or do you want people to debug whatever ChatGPT came up with?

Comment: This cannot be easily done because this depends on the font size which affects the terminal/gvim grid size. You need to know the height and width of the grid cell, which you can try to calculate but that will not be pixel perfect.